# PHP AJAX Live Search - Placing GIF Loader Icon

Tags: php, ajax

Currently i am using this script for live search

```
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp
```

But the issue is i want a gif loading image in search box right position when user type something and hide it when results shows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your logic inside the `showResult` function:

```
<script>
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
    /// HERE hide the image ----------------------------
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  /// HERE show the image ---------------------------
}
</script>
```

Do you know the code to create an IMG element and append it next to the input box?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, can you please provide a working example on jsfiddle or codepen.